# How to write fetchXml to get distinct data in dataverse connector

Tags: power-automate, dataverse

I am creating flow where I am using Data verse Connector and written fetchXml to get data from **checklistquestionresponse**, **annotation** and **checklistasset** entities, but in **annotation** holds multiple records for one **checklistquestionresponse** entity record due to which it show duplicate records, we just want to check if any record present in **annotation** entity for current query record of **checklistquestionresponse** entity. How can I do this, please refer below fetchXml query :

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
<entity name="checklistquestionresponse">
<attribute name="checklistquestionresponseid" />
<attribute name="title" />
<attribute name="instructions" />
<attribute name="notes" />    
<attribute name="checklist" />
<order attribute="title" descending="false" />
<link-entity name="annotation" from="objectid" to="checklistquestionresponseid" link-type="outer" alias="ae">
     <attribute name="annotationid" />
</link-entity>
<link-entity name="checklistasset" from="checklistassetid" to="checklistasset" visible="false" link-type="outer" alias="checklistasset">
  <attribute name="name" />
</link-entity>
<filter type="and">
  <condition attribute="checklist" operator="eq" uitype="checklist" value="@{triggerOutputs()?'body/checklistid']}}" />
 <filter type="or">
 <condition attribute="notes" operator="not-null" />
 <condition entityname="ae" attribute="annotationid" operator="not-null" />
</filter>
  <filter type="or">
    <condition attribute="acceptableunacceptablerange" operator="eq" value="Acceptable" />
    <condition attribute="responsevalue" operator="eq" value="Acceptable" />
   </filter>
  </filter>
 </entity>
</fetch>
```

To resolve this problem what should I do, should I create multiple data verse connector, if I use multiple data verse connector how can i check into html table for each checklistquestionresponse entity record.
[image]

Please advice.

Thanks in advance,
Sandy

Answer (score 0):

You can use `distinct="true"` in your fetchXml to remove duplicates in the returned dataset.

Check [this blog](https://markcarrington.dev/2020/04/03/inside-fetchxml-pt-9-distinct/) out for some more information on how distinct works